# Save R source codes in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I would like to write several R source codes in a loop. However I am not getting a functional source file. That´s what I tried:

```
for(k in 1:10){
    cod <- 'x <- 1+k
         nam <- paste0(x, ".txt")
         write.table(x, nam)'
    cod <- gsub("x", k, cod)
    file <- paste0("source", k, ".R")
    dput(cod, file=file)}
```

Strictly speaking, I would like to get exactly the code in the `cod` object in 10 sources codes (differing by the `k`, which go from 1 to 10). Actually this code produce all the 10 files, but they contain strange characters and are no functional at all.

Comment: Replace `dput` with `writeLines(cod, file)`

Comment: `dput` writes an ASCII text representation of an R object, it's not mean for saving output. Use `writeLines`, `sink`, `cat`

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to do this? It seems very strange. What are you doing with these R files once you've made them? Also, your first line ends up as things like `5 <- 1+k` because you substitute `x` with the value of `k`. What is going on?

Comment: @Spacedman, probably there is a much faster way to do what I want. Nevertheless, using several source codes is possible to run much faster than a canonical loop.

Comment: Why is it faster? Because you can run them in parallel? Sure, but don't duplicate the code. Put the code in *one* file as a function can call that from 10 scripts that just have `source("code.R"); dothing(1)` and `dothing(2)` and so on. Or better still *parameterise* the script and use `littler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify to writeLines from put, also change your formatting of string as follow:

```
for(k in 1:10) {
  cod <- 'x <- 1+k\nnam <- paste0(x, ".txt")\nwrite.table(x, nam)'
  cod <- gsub("x", k, cod)
  file <- paste0("source", k, ".R");
  writeLines(cod, file)
}
```

Comment: It worked well! However, in my real code I have some characters which seems to be missed in the final source.R files. For example, I used `write.table(x, nam, sep="\t")`, which is modified wrongly to `write.table(x, nam, sep="    ")`. Do you have any idea to deal with that?

Comment: Sometimes, `\t` will look like a space given the width of other data columns, but yet may be a tab. Also, make sure to use `row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE` options to write.table.

Comment: I also got a problem in another section with the `\` character:  `list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$")` was been turned into `list.files(pattern = "\.txt$")` given the follow error when I tried to execute the source: `Error: '\.' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\."
Execution halted`